# How to properly migrate Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, rest

I have my laravel project and copied to another folder. I have changed the name of the app and my AJAX requests stopped working. GET works fine but POST,PUT methods either return '405 Method not allowed' or '500 Internal error'.

I am not acquainted with Laravel so could you please tell me what I possibly didn't do? Is there some REST config file where I configure routes?

Comment: Any errors in the logs?

Comment: There is nothing in logs. Before copying application worked on the server and is using oauth2. After copying to other server I changed names in every file for example: 'www.example.com' to 'www.example1.com'

Comment: Oauth2 works - I checked that with Postman. It correctly returned access_token. After I log in as user nothing is inserted into oauth tables in database

Comment: Your routes will either be in **routes/api.php** or **routes/web.php**. It sounds like they’ve been set up to response to `GET` requests only. Laravel docs on routing: http://laravel.com/docs/master/routing